# compiling ffmpeg and chromaprint for android with success on some devices

Tags: android, compilation, ffmpeg

I am following the recommendations of this site:

https://bitbucket.org/phorton1/chromaprint

From the site I have copied the `multi-configure` and `multi-make` scripts for the ffmpeg and chromaprint libraries. I have used them with recent clones of ffmpeg 3.0 and chromaprint 1.3.2 . I get working '.so' files for arm, x86 and armv7. I don't have compillation problems. I load them into my app (a very simple app just to test this library) and  I try it on my two devices. One is a Samsung Galaxy TabPro (SM-T320, api 19), and one is the Samsung S4 (api 21). I get the program to run on both. I can use the '-version' command to get the chromaprint version info. When I try to fingerprint a audio file, the software works on the older tablet, but not on the s4. On the s4 the error message is 'error decoding audio'.

I have tried ffmpeg 0.9 as the bitbucket site suggests. I have the same problem. I have tried ffmpeg 2.7 and I thought this was working. Now I cannot get 2.7 to work. As before the code works on the api 19 device and not the s4.

The Tab is an armeabi-v7a device and the s4 is an armeabi/armeabi-v7 device, so I thought by removing the 'armeabi' binary I would have the same file on both machines, and they would have to work. This attempt did nothing. I am using android studio.

Below is a list of some of my ffmpeg configurations. They are taken from the multi-configure script.

```
    --enable-static
    --disable-shared
    --disable-doc
    --disable-txtpages
    --disable-iconv

    --enable-memalign-hack
    --enable-debug
    --disable-avdevice
    --disable-avfilter
    --disable-swscale
    --disable-ffmpeg
    --disable-ffplay
    --disable-ffserver
    --disable-network
    --disable-muxers
    --disable-demuxers
    --enable-rdft
    --enable-demuxer=aac
    --enable-demuxer=ac3
    --enable-demuxer=ape
    --enable-demuxer=asf
    --enable-demuxer=flac
    --enable-demuxer=matroska_audio
    --enable-demuxer=mp3
    --enable-demuxer=mpc
    --enable-demuxer=mov
    --enable-demuxer=mpc8
    --enable-demuxer=ogg
    --enable-demuxer=tta
    --enable-demuxer=wav
    --enable-demuxer=wv
    --disable-bsfs
    --disable-filters
    --disable-parsers
    --enable-parser=aac
    --enable-parser=ac3
    --enable-parser=mpegaudio
    --disable-protocols
    --enable-protocol=file
    --disable-indevs
    --disable-outdevs
    --disable-encoders
    --disable-decoders
    --enable-decoder=aac
    --enable-decoder=ac3
    --enable-decoder=alac
    --enable-decoder=ape
    --enable-decoder=flac
    --enable-decoder=mp1
    --enable-decoder=mp2
    --enable-decoder=mp3
    --enable-decoder=mpc7
    --enable-decoder=mpc8
    --enable-decoder=tta
    --enable-decoder=vorbis
    --enable-decoder=wavpack
    --enable-decoder=wmav1
    --enable-decoder=wmav2
    --enable-decoder=pcm_alaw
    --enable-decoder=pcm_dvd
    --enable-decoder=pcm_f32be
    --enable-decoder=pcm_f32le
    --enable-decoder=pcm_f64be
    --enable-decoder=pcm_f64le
    --enable-decoder=pcm_s16be
    --enable-decoder=pcm_s16le
    --enable-decoder=pcm_s16le_planar
    --enable-decoder=pcm_s24be
    --enable-decoder=pcm_daud
    --enable-decoder=pcm_s24le
    --enable-decoder=pcm_s32be
    --enable-decoder=pcm_s32le
    --enable-decoder=pcm_s8
    --enable-decoder=pcm_u16be
    --enable-decoder=pcm_u16le
    --enable-decoder=pcm_u24be
    --enable-decoder=pcm_u24le
    --enable-decoder=rawvideo
```

Here is some information about the s4 that I got from a system info app.

```
Build Info
    Build.BOARD: MSM8960
    Build.BRAND: Verizon
    Build.DEVICE: jfltevzw
    Build.DISPLAY: LRX22C.I545VRUGOF1
    Build.PRODUCT: jfltevzw
    Build.HARDWARE: qcom
    Build.FINGERPRINT: Verizon/jfltevzw/jfltevzw:5.0.1/LRX22C/I545VRUGOF1:user/release-keys
    Build.CPU_ABI: armeabi-v7a
    Build.SUPPORTED_32_BIT_ABIS: [armeabi-v7a, armeabi]
    Build.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS: []
    Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS: [armeabi-v7a, armeabi]
    Build.HOST: SWDD6122
    Build.ID: LRX22C
    Build.MANUFACTURER: samsung
    Build.MODEL: SCH-I545
    Build.PRODUCT: jfltevzw
    Build.TAGS: release-keys
    Build.TIME: 2015-07-15T03:39:01.000-0400
    Build.TYPE: user
    Build.USER: dpi
    Build.BOOTLOADER: I545VRUGOF1
    Build.TAGS: release-keys
    Build.VERSION.CODENAME: REL
    Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL: I545VRUGOF1
    Build.VERSION.RELEASE: 5.0.1
    Build.VERSION.SDK_INT: 21
```

**EDIT:**

This is the complete source for my project minus the api-key which is personal. https://github.com/radiodee1/awesome-fpcalc  The code is arranged in parts inside the git repository. The 'fpcalc-testapp' part just has the Android Studio project. The 'fpcalc-build' part is my attempt to use the latest versions of ffmpeg, chromaprint, and kissfft. The 'fpcalc-build-complete' part is a series of scripts that reproduces the P. Horton ffmpeg 2.7 scenario. Bye the way I believe the best libraries are produced in the 'build-complete' folders.

Comment: I am using ndk r12b.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that chromaprint supports kiss-fft as a supplement for ffmpeg. It is specifically recommend for android in the NEWS file in the chromaprint git repository. I looked up kiss-fft. It's small. I found it at the URL below :

https://sourceforge.net/projects/kissfft/

Instead of compiling the libraries separately I copied the sources of kiss-fft into the chromaprint 'src' folder. (I moved the 'tools' folder also.) Then I modified the make file for chromaprint. First I replaced the occurrence of `WITH_AVFFT=ON` with `WITH_KISSFFT=ON`. Then I only needed to add one more line.

```
    COBJS += $(BUILD_DIR)/src/kiss_fft.o
```

Then I compiled ffmpeg and chromaprint as I had originally. The resulting binaries were slightly larger and seem to work with both of my devices. The problem with this is that the solution is messy. You have to copy all the kiss-fft sources to the chromaprint 'src' folder. The other problem is that you are not eliminating ffmpeg from the build. This last issue is something I would like to figure out.

I will not include the entire make file here.  Thanks to anyone reading this for all help.

Comment: I'm wrong. This does not fix the problem on both devices. I answered my question too quickly.

Comment: Hi, any luck?Let's talk about it and do something together . I am working on audio fingerprinting too. My email is ankitsrivastava0193@gmail.com